# How can i show Strings from strings.xml in java class array

Tags: java, android, string

I want to show strings from strings.xml in my items.java. if i declare it as String i get stuck with an error, if i declare it as int, i only see some numbers but not my String. Perhaps someone can help me?

Here are my files

item.java file

```
public class Item {

private static final String LARGE_BASE_URL = "http://storage.googleapis.com/androiddevelopers/sample_data/activity_transition/large/";
private static final String THUMB_BASE_URL = "http://storage.googleapis.com/androiddevelopers/sample_data/activity_transition/thumbs/";


public static Item[] ITEMS = new Item[] {
        new Item(0,
                "Über die App",
                "",
                R.drawable.appicon,
                R.drawable.appicon,
                "Meerforellen Guide - Ostsee",
                R.string.about
        ),
        new Item(10,
                "Die Leidenschaft",
                "",
                R.drawable.imgp1262,
                R.drawable.imgp1262,
                "Ein Einblick in den Alltag",
                R.string.leidenschaft
        ),
        new Item(15,
                "Die Technik",
                "",
                R.drawable.imgp0817,
                R.drawable.imgp0817,
                "Spinn und Fliegenfischen",
                R.string.lorem
        ),
        new Item(17,
                "Rechtliche Bestimmungen",
                "",
                R.drawable.imgp0831,
                R.drawable.imgp0831,
                "Dies gibt es zu beachten",
                R.string.lorem
        ),
        new Item(18,
                "Ferienwohnungen/Häuser",
                "",
                R.drawable.imgp0819,
                R.drawable.imgp0819,
                "Unterkünfte - dicht am Fisch",
                R.string.lorem
        ),
        new Item(20,
                "Übersicht der Spots",
                "",
                R.drawable.mapindex,
                R.drawable.mapindex,
                "Von Nord nach Süd",
                R.string.spots
        ),

        new Item(30,
                "01 - Habernis",
                "Na de Huk\n24972 Steinburg\n",
                R.drawable.pic,
                R.drawable.r_habernis,
                "Geo: 54.793909, 9.793722",
                R.string.lorem
        ),

        new Item(40,
                "02 - Falshöft",
                "Sibbeskjär\n24395 Pommerby\n",
                R.drawable.pic,
                R.drawable.r_falshoeft,
                "Geo: 54.76851, 9.96507",
                R.string.lorem
        ),
        new Item(50,
                "04 - Hasselberg",
                "Drecht\n24376 Hasselberg\n",
                R.drawable.pic,
                R.drawable.r_hasselberg,
                "Geo: 54.7201, 9.98752",
                R.string.lorem
        ),
        new Item(60,
                "05 Schönhagen",
                "Nordhagener Straße\n24398 Brodersby\n",
                R.drawable.pic,
                R.drawable.r_schoenhagen,
                "Geo: 54.63184, 10.03242",
                R.string.lorem
        ),
        new Item(70,
                "06 Waabs / Langholz",
                "Ostseestraße\n24369 Waabs\n",
                R.drawable.pic,
                R.drawable.r_waabs,
                "Geo: 54.51607, 9.98766",
                R.string.lorem
        ),
        new Item(80,
                "07 Noer",
                "Zum Hegenwohld 35\n24214 Noer\n",
                R.drawable.pic,
                R.drawable.r_noer,
                "Geo: 54.46922, 10.00011",
                R.string.lorem
        ),
        new Item(90,
                "08 Surendorf",
                "Zum Kurstrand\n24229 Schwedeneck\n",
                R.drawable.pic,
                R.drawable.r_surendorf,
                "Geo: 54.47992, 10.07472",
                R.string.lorem
        ),
        new Item(100,
                "09 Bülk",
                "Bülker Weg\n24229 Strande\n",
                R.drawable.pic,
                R.drawable.r_buelk,
                "Geo: 54.45571, 10.19875",
                R.string.lorem
        ),
        new Item(110,
                "10 Brasilien",
                "Deichweg 2\n24217 Schönberg\n",
                R.drawable.pic,
                R.drawable.r_brasilien,
                "Geo: 54.42693, 10.38323",
                R.string.lorem
        ),
        new Item(120,
                "11 Hohenfelde",
                "Malmsteg\n24257 Hohenfelde\n",
                R.drawable.pic,
                R.drawable.r_hohenfelde,
                "Geo: 54.38568, 10.50348",
                R.string.lorem
        ),
        new Item(130,
                "12 Behrensdorf",
                "Strandstraße\n24321 Behrensdorf\n",
                R.drawable.pic,
                R.drawable.r_behrensdorf,
                "Geo: 54.3602, 10.608",
                R.string.lorem
        ),
        new Item(140,
                "13 Lippe",
                "Lippe 3\n24321 Behrensdorf\n",
                R.drawable.pic,
                R.drawable.r_lippe,
                "Geo: 54.33767, 10.64692",
                R.string.lorem
        ),
        new Item(150,
                "14 Hohwacht",
                "Dünenweg 6\n24321 Hohwacht\n",
                R.drawable.pic,
                R.drawable.r_hohwacht,
                "Geo: 54.32274, 10.67195",
                R.string.lorem
        ),

};

public static Item getItem(int id) {
    for (Item item : ITEMS) {
        if (item.getId() == id) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
private final int mid;
private final String mName;
private final String mAuthor;
private final int mFileName;
private final int mFileName2;
private final String mGeo;
private final int mBeitrag;



Item(int id, String name, String author, int fileName, int fileName2, String geo, int beitrag) {
    mid = id;
    mName = name;
    mAuthor = author;
    mFileName = fileName;
    mFileName2 = fileName2;
    mGeo = geo;
    mBeitrag = beitrag;

}

public int getId() {
    return mid;
}
public String getGeo() {
    return mGeo;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return mAuthor;
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}
public int getBeitrag() { return mBeitrag; }
public int getPhotoUrl() {
    return mFileName2;
}

public int getThumbnailUrl() {
    return mFileName;
}
```

}

strings.xml

```
<string name="bericht">%1$s %2$s</string>
<string name="bericht2">%1$s</string>
<string name="image_header">%1$s</string>
<string name="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</string>
<string name="about">Version 1.6 http://www.mefoguide-app.de http://www.facebook.de Kontakt: info@mefoguide-app.de Quellen:     SplashScreen-Bild: Andre Pricken     Leidenschaft-Bild: Jochen Feuerschütz     Technik-Bild: Jochen Feuerschütz     Rechtliche Bestimmungen Bild: Jochen Feuerschütz     Ferienwohnungen/Häuser Bild: Jochen Feuerschütz     www.wikipedia.de www.google.de und natürlich hauptsächlich: persönliche Erfahrung</string>
<string name="leidenschaft">Dieses Bild von Jochen Feuerschütz erklärt eigentlich schon vieles...Der Fisch der 1000 Würfe...Irgendwann hört jeder Angler diesen Spruch und denkt sich  1000 Würfe? Herausforderung angenommen!.Schon bald wird er in der Brandung stehen und werfen und werfen und werfen. Einige brauchen keine 1000 Würfe, andere 3000. Dieser Ratgeber soll Dir dabei Helfen, einer von denen zu sein der keine 1000 Würfe braucht. Mit jedem Update gibt es neue Hotspots. Desweiteren wird auch etwas Theroie zur Biologie folgen. Alleine gute Spots zu kennen ergibt keine Fanggarantie. Mann muss die Lebensgewohnheiten kennen und kann dann viel besser abschätzen, wann es sich nicht lohnt loszuziehen, bzw. welche Strände am vielversprechesten bei aktueller Wetterlage sind.</string>
<string name="spots">01 - Habernis 02 - Falshöft 03 - Kronsgaard 04 - Hasselberg 05 - Schönhagen 06 - Waabs / Langholz 07 - Noer 08 - Surendorf 09 - Bülk 10 - Brasilien 11 - Hohenfelde 12 - Behrensdorf 13 - Lippe 14 - Hohwacht</string>
```

Comment: Instead of using naive objects (`Item`), why don't you use a table of rows from a database, instead?

Answer (score 3):

In strings.xml you can implement your strings as an array, like this:

```
<string-array name="myArray">
    <item>Some text 1</item>
    <item>Some text 2</item>
    <item>Some text 3</item>
    <item>Some text 4</item>
    <item>Some text 5</item>
</string-array>
```

Then, you can get them like this:

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
context.getResources().getString(yourIntegerId)
```

You need pass context to your function and when u call string from xml - call this function.

something like :

```
public String getFilename1(Context context) {
    return context.getResurces().getString(filename1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass on the 'Context' reference to the class and use

```
String your_string = context_reference.getString(R.string.<your_string_id>);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Activity and Fragment you can Directly use

```
getString(R.string.your_string_id)
```

as this Method already has defined by default getResources() tag

```
 /**
     * Return a localized string from the application's package's
     * default string table.
     *
     * @param resId Resource id for the string
     */
    public final String getString(@StringRes int resId) {
        return getResources().getString(resId);
    }
```

If you want to use Array then define array in String XML

```
<string-array name="image_extensions">
        <item>application/jpeg</item>
        <item>application/jpg</item>
        <item>application/bmp</item>
        <item>application/png</item>
        <item>application/gif</item>
    </string-array>
```

and in Java Class get it like this

```
String[] imagemimetypes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.image_extensions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
new Item(150,"14 Hohwacht","Dünenweg 6\n24321 Hohwacht\n",R.drawable.pic,R.drawable.r_hohwacht,"Geo: 54.32274, 10.67195",getResources().getString(R.string.about);),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining strings in your strings.xml.
Whereas you want array of string. In order to achieve that you need to do this.

```
<string-array name="system">
<item>@string/earth</item>
<item>@string/moon</item>
</string-array>
```

This way you can easily access the array.

```
    String[] some_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_string_array)
```